# Post запрос возвращает неизвестные символы Python

Tags: python, post

Делаю post запрос, но получаю какие-то неизвестные символы. Вот код:

```
name_id = 195048
url = 'https://wiki.cs.money/graphql'
body = {"operationName":"price_trader_log","variables":{"name_ids":[name_id]},"query":"query price_trader_log($name_ids: [Int!]!) {\n  price_trader_log(input: {name_ids: $name_ids}) {\n    name_id\n    values {\n      price_trader_new\n      time\n    }\n  }\n}\n"}
headers = {
'Host': 'wiki.cs.money',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://wiki.cs.money/ru/stickers/sticker-adren-katowice-2019',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'Origin': 'https://wiki.cs.money',
'Content-Length': '257',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'TE': 'Trailers',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
res = r.text
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
☺��☺ Z��U⌂�K��☻←8�C�∟�§∟�f���N��♦���� ����cel�c��e)[�N�ݰ���:O↓�▬��◄P��n��n�☻X�KX↓�f��?x���߉��/�§‼%����▲���{\�{dy��7�ogX��S��H���=�=*3[LN�ə�rLn$iD�g3�n�=X←Ũ ���G���{��b���ؙME��K렳2�\Wl&C�*�¶↕↨S�z��/▬�▲t1ټs>G|VF�<X☺��n♠Θr��P...
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Спасибо

Comment: попробовал, нормально вернуло: {"data":{"price_trader_log":[{"name_id":195048,"values":[{"price_trader_new":0.2,"time":1616343729}... а попробуйте res = json.loads(res)?

Comment: @Jack_oS получаю ошибку json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Если у вас всё вышло, может быть у меня что-то с кодировкой консоли? Просто первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь

Comment: Вы в HTTP-заголовках указали, что готовы принять сжатые данные, сервер вам прислал сжатые данные, а вы их испугались. Не нужно бездумно копипастить все подряд HTTP-заголовки без понимания того, для чего они нужны.

Comment: @IIIyTH1K кстати да, попробуйте оставить в заголовках только User-Agent?

Comment: @andreymal до этого никогда не использовал post запросы, поэтому не знаю какие из параметров нужны. Мне нужно что-то убрать?

Comment: @Jack_oS получаю POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?

Comment: а оставить все, кроме Accept-Encoding?

Comment: @Jack_oS да, только хотел написать. Убрал Accept-Encoding и в консоли словарь начал отображаться правильно. Спасибо